# ActionScript: Multiple public functions in one .as file?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

As I've been working with AS I've developed a collection of utility functions. For example:

```
$ cat utils/curried.as
package utils {
public function curried(f:Function, ...boundArgs):Function {
    function curriedHelper(...dynamicArgs):* {
        return f.apply(null, boundArgs.concat(dynamicArgs));
    }
    return curriedHelper;
}
}
```

And I've found that, some times, I want to keep more than one public function in each file... But ActionScript restricts me to one public definition per file, if that file defines its self as being part of a package.

So, without creating a class with static methods, how could I get more than one public function in a single `.as` file?

Comment: what is the reason against using a class?

Comment: I don't want to have a prefix on the functions when I'm using them. Eg, I want to use "curried(foo, bar)" instead of "Utils.curried(foo, bar)".

Comment: I'd have to ask the other way around, why not use multiple files?
AS3 allows one public declaration per file, this is the same for functions as for classes.

Doesn't it make sense to keep one per file? (disk space is cheap, and you can still do wild card imports ).

I don't understand the suggestions for putting functions as static methods on a class. A class is a different abstraction than a function. People do that in Java, simply because the language does not allow for stand alone functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

simply put, you can't ... for a package level function declaration, you need one file per declared function ...

little side note: personally, i'd go Josh's way and stuff them into a class ... i think allowing function level declarations at all was simply to have a bit more backward compatibility to AS2 ... it's ok, for prototyping or things that'll never leave your hands ... but you imagine relying on 3-4 libraries, each exposing their functionality through package level functions? firstly, it completely spams your autocompletion (if your IDE offers one), and secondly, you always need to look at the imports to see which function comes from where ... the prefix you mentioned is actually of great advantage ... but ok, that's my opinion ...

greetz

back2dos

Comment: Thanks – I hadn't considered, eg, the autocomplete spam.