# Accessing a class with access specifier "Internal" from the FLA library

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to access an "Internal" class Abc , by a movieclip ( with class name : Abc ). I cannot specify it public for some reasons. How can i access it ?

Comment: You cannot, this is how internal classes in ActionScript work, only one public class is allowed per file the inner class I believe would need it's own file to be accessible by other classes.  See a similar post on SO here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126678/actionscript-multiple-public-functions-in-one-as-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#internal

an internal class is only available to other classes that live in the same EXACT package.
make a class that lives in the same package and you can access it.

let's use this example

```
package com.app {
    internal class Abc { }
}

package com.app.sub { 
    public class OtherClass {
        // classes in sub package cannot access or any other package
        // attempting to instantiate a class when outside its package
        // results in a compiler error
    }
}

package com.app {
    public class UsesAbc {
        function UsesAbc () {
            var abc:Abc = new Abc();
            // this is ok because they live in exactly the same package
            // this class can be use as a proxy for Abc
            // because the class is public
        }
    }
}
```